# How to add comments etc to django-photologue photos?

Tags: photos, pinax, photologue

I am trying to make use of a powerful feature in  photologue which is batch uplad. The app  comes with Pinax but not fully implemented. Pinax only makes use of 'Photos'.  I want to add  all comment,avatar, tags etc which come in a 'photo' page into the photos that are originally uploaded through zip upload.

I could not find any resources about this integration. So appreciate your hints.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the documentation at http://code.google.com/p/django-photologue/? This describes the gallery upload feature.